# Open Multiple Links Simultaneously with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Can I just enquire if it is possible to create open multiple tabs with window.open?

The link in the codes below will download PDF and I will need to download it at one go. I am opening links created dynamically. I am sending the values - $ids from a checkbox form to the controller below.

Codes below are placed in a .php file.

```
if (Tools::isSubmit('submitlabels')) {

$ids= Tools::getValue('awaiting');

echo "<script>";
   foreach ($ids as $updateids) {
      $url = '/webtools/index.php?controller=Adminxxx&type=returnlabel&id_order='.$updateids.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('Adminxxx');
      echo "window.open('$url')";
      }
      echo "</script>";
      }
```

I have checked on multiple solutions online and currently, I am stuck at this portion. It will only download when I choose 1 value from checkbox. Multiple values will not download any PDF.

Any guidance is truly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this technique

```
if (Tools::isSubmit('submitlabels')) {

$ids= Tools::getValue('awaiting');

   foreach ($ids as $updateids) {
      $url = '/webtools/index.php?controller=Adminxxx&type=returnlabel&id_order='.$updateids.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('Adminxxx');
?>
  <script>
      var url = <?= $url; ?>;
      $("<a>").attr("href", url).attr("target", "_blank")[0].click();
    </script>

     <?php }
      }
```

This code will open a new tab

Comment: I am placing my code in a .php file. I have tried your code but it is returning an error.  Can you assist with combining with my codes?

Comment: Thanks for updating the code, it is returning syntax error unfortunately.

Comment: you need to some debugging or share the error message

Comment: syntax error. unexpected var. What does this line do btw? - var url = <?= $url; ?>;...... If I were to use this $("<a>").attr("href", $url).attr("target", "_blank")[0].click();.... this error will occur: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$

Comment: ok my mistake because it should be url instead of $url in the attr()

Answer (score 0):

Managed to scrape this through with the codes below:

```
foreach ($ids as $updateids) {
$url = '/webtools/index.php?controller=Adminxxx&type=label&id_order='.$updateids.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('Adminxxx');

echo "<script>";
    echo "window.open('$url')";
echo "</script>";
    }
}
```